# Partitioning hard-drive to correct mistake

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have been given a friends laptop who tried to re-partition the hard drive while reinstalling Windows XP. The problem is the way to drives were partitioned.

The C:\ is the (System) partition and is 100 MB

The D:\ is the (Boot) partition and contains the remainder of the drive space.

The problem is I can not alter the sizes of the partitions system or boot volumes so I am stuck. I tried reinstalling from the CD but there is not enough space on the C: drive to perform the initial setup so I get a BSOD before the partitioning utility loads.

This laptop does not have a floppy disk drive so I can't use a boot disk.

How do I change the partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest Making the Ultimate Book CD http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ (Free) and comes with many tools that will help. Especially what you are looking for is a partition utility. Fdisk I believe is the particular tool you will be using to redo your partitions. Another option is also to use a linux live CD, and use gparted. Either way, you can delete all partitions and then create just one large partition to put the Windows install on.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Ultimate Boot CD, you can also use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/), a Linux based LiveCD that is aimed essentially at thik kind of jobs.